# SQL DataReader how to show null-values from query

Tags: c#, sql, stringbuilder, datareader

I have a DataReader and a StringBuilder (C#.NET) used in the following way;

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    sb.AppendFormat("{0},{1},{2},",reader["Col1"], reader["Col2"], reader["Col3"]);
}
```

Which works great for my use, but when a row is null I need it to return "null", instead of just "". What would be a good way of accomplishing that?

Suggestions are very appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
Convert.IsDBNull(reader["Col1"]) ? "null" : reader["Col1"]
```

Alternatively, if you're going to be using this repeatedly, this is probably an ideal candidate for a tightly scoped Extension Method, for example:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static object GetValueOrNull(this SqlDataReader reader, string key)
    {
        return Convert.IsDBNull(reader[key]) ? (object)"null" : reader[key];
    }
}
```

So you could then write:

```
var valueOfReader = reader.GetValueOrNull("Col1");
```

Which would definately make things tidier if you needed to use this logic multiple times inside one `StringBuilder.AppendFormat` call:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    sb.AppendFormat("{0},{1},{2},",reader.GetValueOrNull("Col1"), reader.GetValueOrNull("Col2"), reader.GetvalueOrNull("Col3"));
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you very much for taking the time to write up all of that.

Comment: Of course, if you did go down the extension method route, you could return anything (such as a value you pass in) if it's null, not just "null" - which would make it more flexible =)

Comment: The simple code works great, it seems however that "this SqlDataReader" doesn't work in a static context. And "the name 'reader' does not exist in the current context". Do you have a quick comment on how to fix those? I'm unfortunately fairly newbie here.

Comment: Ahh my bad - sorry, I missed something - I've edited the extension method accordingly :)

Comment: @Rob - Thanks for taking the time! I very much appreciate it. I managed to get your code working.

Answer (score 4):

```
reader["Col1"] == DBNull.Value ? "null" : Convert.ToString(reader["Col1"])
```

Comment: I voted to delete my answer, which was the same.  I was a few seconds too late!

Answer (score 1):

```
reader.IsDBNull(indexOfColumn) ? "null" : reader[indexOfColumn].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(string)reader["Col1"] ?? "null"
```